# Why is the first SaveChanges slower than following calls?

Tags: ravendb

I'm investigating some performance problems in an experimental scheduling application I'm working on. I found that calls to `session.SaveChanges()` were pretty slow, so I wrote a simple test.

Can you explain why the first iteration of the loop takes 200ms and subsequent loop 1-2 ms? How I can I leverage this in my application (I don't mind the first call to be this slow if all subsequent calls are quick)?

```
private void StoreDtos()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        StoreNewSchedule();
    }
}

private void StoreNewSchedule()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        session.Store(NewSchedule());
        session.SaveChanges();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Persisting schedule took {0} ms.", 
      sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Output is:

```
Persisting schedule took 189 ms. // first time
Persisting schedule took 2 ms.   // second time
Persisting schedule took 1 ms.   // ... etc
```

Above is for an in-memory database. Using a http connection to a Raven DB instance (on the same machine), I get similar results. The first call takes noticeably more time:

```
Persisting schedule took 1116 ms.
Persisting schedule took 37 ms.
Persisting schedule took 14 ms.
```

On Github: [RavenDB 2.0 testcode](https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/tree/master/ravendb/WhyIsMyFirstSaveSoSlowRaven20) and [RavenDB 2.5 testcode](https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/tree/master/ravendb/WhyIsMyFirstSaveSoSlowRaven25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first time that you call RavenDB, there are several things that have to happen.

- We need to prepare the serializers for your entities, which takes time.
- We need to create the TCP connection to the server.

On the next calls, we can reuse the connection that is already open and the created serializers.

Comment: Is there any way to perform some kind of warmup?

Comment: Just make a request to RavenDB, it would handle a lot of the cost, yes.